# Need help on scraping php

Tags: php, web-scraping

I have this code to scrape data from a website.

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.alanum.com/search.aspx?kw=GTX%20980');             //get the html returned from the following url

$pk_doc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors

if(!empty($html)){ //if any html is actually returned

$pokemon_doc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

$pk_xpath = new DOMXPath($pk_doc);

//get all the h2's with an id
$pk_row = $pk_xpath->query('//h4[@name="list-productname"]');
$pk_row2 = $pk_xpath->query('//div[@class="price"]');

if($pk_row->length > 0){
    foreach($pk_row as $row){
        echo $row->nodeValue . "<br/>";
    }
}
if($pk_row2->length > 0){
    foreach($pk_row2 as $row2){
        echo $row2->nodeValue . "<br/>";
    }
}
}
?>
```

I am new to web scraping so how do I skip a tag for instance if

```
'//div[@class]'
```

This is getting all the divs that have class but I want to skip some of the divs that I do not want. How do I do that?

One more question is how do I combine `$pk_row` and `$pk_row2` because `$pk_row` has name and `$pk_row2` has prices.

I want one single array to have those values inside.
`name=>` and `price=>`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify which elements you want to skip i can only refer you to  http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp where you may find what you need.

**Edit:** `'//div[not(@class="name-enlarged")]'`

For combining two arrays so one is used for keys and other one for values you can use `array_combine($arrKeys, $arrValues)` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Comment: '//div[@class="name-enlarged"]' if this div has to be skipped then is it going to be '//div[@class!="name-enlarged"]'?

Comment: '//div[not(@class="name-enlarged")]'